# python ControlScripts/control.py /dev/tty.PathToUsbDevice - Can't find correct path

Tags: python, python-3.x, arduino

Windows 7 Professional 64 bit, Service Pack 1

I am stuck at Step 4 of Software on a DIY automatic Etch-A-Sketch drawing project.

http://www.evanlong.org/projects/etching/

python ControlScripts/control.py /dev/tty.PathToUsbDevice

Running from the command prompt as administrator all attempts end with

```
C:\Windows\system32>python ControlScripts/control.py dev/tty.PathToUsbDevice python: can't open file ControlScripts/control.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

This link is to the actual chipset in my device.

https://www.silabs.com/community/interface/knowledge-base.entry.html/2013/11/21/windows_usb_devicep-aGxD

Which shows the steps for finding the "Finding the Device Path Parameters using Device Manager"

```
Device Description: Silicon Labs CP210x USB to UART Bridge

Device Instance Path: USB\VID_10C4&PID_EA60\0190F200

Location Information: Port_#0001.Hub_#0001
```

It appears that I can communicate with the board (adafruit Metro) on COM 5 using Arduino.

The board starts out with blinking LEDS and after uploading, both the red and green LED are steady.

The preceding steps seem to have completed successfully.

```
Installed c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packag
es\pillow-5.4.1-py3.6-win-amd64.egg
Processing dependencies for pillow
Finished processing dependencies for pillow

-----

Installed c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packag
es\pyserial-3.4-py3.6.egg
Processing dependencies for pyserial
Finished processing dependencies for pyserial
```

What I get.

```
C:\Windows\system32>python ControlScripts/control.py /dev/tty.USB\VID_10C4&PID_EA60\0190F200
python: can't open file 'ControlScripts/control.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory The system cannot find the path specified.

-----

C:\Windows\system32>python ControlScripts/control.py /dev/USB\VID_10C4&PID_EA60\0190F200
python: can't open file 'ControlScripts/control.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory The system cannot find the path specified.
```

What is the correct path for the device?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues you need to look into.

1. You are trying to reference a python file with the wrong path.
2. You are trying to reference a com port using a path that applies to lniux based systems.

To solve both these issue, you will have to do the following.

1. Download the repo from the link in the project. Click [here](https://github.com/evanlong/etching/archive/master.zip) to download the repo as a zip file.
2. unzip the file into a folder and open the folder.
3. From the address bar of the file explorer, copy the location of the folder.
4. From the terminal use the following command to go to the folder location

   cd path/to/unzipped/folder
5. From tools>port in arduino find the com port for your device. It should be something like "com3" or "com5".
6. run your python command as follows. The example assumes that the port name is com3

   python ControlScripts/control.py "com3"